# ShellExecute не работает

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня не работает в коде ShellExecute.
Ничего не подчеркивается, но при компиляции выскакивают не дающие мне никакой информации ошибки в файле .obj [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Использовал этот код:

```
#include <windows.h>
...
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"http://www.cyberforum.ru", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

И различные его вариации, ошибки повторяются. Прошу помочь с решением или предложить альтернативные варианты, спасибо.

Comment: И до кучи, если используете wide символы, желательно строго определять функцию, не надеясь на автодетект, в вашем случае `ShellExecuteW(..)`

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы `ShellExecute` заработал, нужно в дополнение к `windows.h` подключить соответствующий заголовочный файл. Конкретно для `ShellExecute` это `shellapi.h`.

На будущее используйте простой алгоритм действий. Если функция WinAPI не находится, открываете гугл и вводите ее название, например, [так](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=ShellExecute&btnK=Google%20Search&oq=ShellExecute). Прямо самой первой идет ссылка на [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea). Открываете и прокручиваете вниз до конца, там находится раздел Requirements, где и указано все, что для данной функции требуется.

Comment: `shellapi.h` инклюдится в `windows.h`, в вопросе ошибка линкера

Comment: Ответ то правильный, доки смотреть надо :) и подключить `Shell32.lib`

Comment: Большое спасибо вам, NewView, ваше дополнение как и ответ выше помогло. Сам бы не догадался, нужно получше изучить эту тему с линкерами)

Comment: @NewView, странно, посмотрел у себя пару проектов где используется `ShellExecute`, нигде не подключается `Shell32.lib`. Ну может просмотрел чего, отвечал уже поздно ночью.

Comment: @VTT, да, верно - `shellapi.h` у меня было указано в проекте, где было определено `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.